# Generating zip file in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am generating multiple .csv files using a script which is plugged in to my Flask app. Below is my route file section where required inputs are taken and passing in to the script.

```
@app.route('/summary_report', methods= ['GET', 'POST'])
def summary_report():
    """
    Showing page for generating daily report
    :return:
    """
    form = frm.SummaryReportForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        from_date = form.from_date.data
        is_active = form.is_active.data
        reports = current_summary_report.fetch_report(from_date=from_date, status=is_active) # Go the script
        return send_file(reports, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename="reports.zip") # Download attachment
    return render_template('pages/reports/current/summary.html', form=form)
```

And my script file is running a loop and creating multiple csv files.

```
def fetch_report(from_date=from_date, status=is_active):
    for record in records:
        ....
        f = open(file_name + '-' + str(time) + '.csv','w+')
        f.write(csv)
        f.close()
```

What changes I should do here to make all csv files in to a zip file and making it downloadable.

Answer (score 0):

Python allows you to quickly create zip/tar archives.

Following command will zip entire directory

```
shutil.make_archive(output_filename, 'zip', dir_name)
```

Following command gives you control on the files you want to archive

```
ZipFile.write(filename)
```

Code Explanation

1. Import make_archive class from module shutil.
2. Use the split function to split out the directory and the file name from the path to the location of the text file.
3. Then we call the module "shutil.make_archive("guru99 archive, "zip", root_dir)" to create archive file, which will be in zip format